# How to debug why my objects/arrays code in Java is not adding items to a bag?

Tags: java

I have to write a program that has white balls and black balls inside a bag and I have to take out 2 at a time and different things happen depending on the colour of the ball that is picked up. The way I want to do this is make a class "bag" and have two different objects of white balls and black balls inside with different properties. (Please don't mind the code I was experimenting a lot, the structure might not be the best.)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
/**
You have 20 black balls and 16 white balls in a bag. You repeat the following
operation until a single ball is left in the bag. You remove two balls at a time. If they are of the
same color, you add a black ball to the bag; if they are of different colors, you add a white ball to
the bag. Outline an algorithm that predicts the color of the last ball left in the bag
 */

public class Bag {
    private int amount;
    private String colour;
    private int totalInside = white.amount + black.amount;
    static Bag white = new Bag(16, "White");
    static Bag black = new Bag(20, "Black");


    public Bag(int number, String bOrW) {
        amount = number;
        colour = bOrW;
    }


    public static void main (String[]args) {
        String[] bagArray = new String[]{white.colour, black.colour};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bagArray));
        

    }
}
```

As you can see I want to assign those objects properties such as the amount of them in a bag and their colour. What I want to do is fill an array with 16 white and 20 black, but I am having a hard time doing so. The main method right now shows error that bagArray is null. It's not adding those objects in the array.

Side question: does it matter if I make the objects in the instance fields or the main method?

Comment: This site is not a homework-writing service. This is not a programming problem, but rather a logic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why null

Your NullPointerException is raised at this line:
`private int totalInside = white.amount + black.amount;`

The reason of this NPE is that you don't understand the execution order of constructors. Static constructor execute before any constructor.

So your program executes in this order:

1. First, It executes your static constructor which is `static Bag white = new Bag(16, "White");`.
2. Then it call the constructor and execute `private int totalInside = white.amount + black.amount;`. But at this time the `white` variable has not been assigned, it is null. Of course you end up with a NPE.

## Solution

According to your description, I think you should have two Classes. One is Ball class which has color property, one is Bag class containing a list of Ball Objects.
You create the Bag class in Main method and fill it with 20 balck ball and 16 white ball. Then execute the algorithm you specifited to see what happens.